# Algorithm for Generating Symmetric Pictures

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

Hi I just joined and have a simple question. You know the patterns that we get when we join? Does anyone have an algorithm or program to generate them? I am also interested in progrms or algorithms that can generate "Mandalas" (Tibetan or Buddhist). I am nor sure what makes a picture a mandala, except that usually they are approximately circular and have various levels of symmetry. Any leads or answers would be appreciated!

Ravi

Answer (score 3):

Those patterns are called **identicons**. You can read more about them and how they're generated **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon)**. You can see and download a sample PHP implementation of the concept [**here**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/identicons/).

Comment: This answer has the highest total thus far, but it's definitely not what the question's author was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Do a google search on the "17 Wallpaper Patterns".

It's a fascinating area if you are interested in this. When I last looked (10 years ago) there were several applications that generated them. I wrote one in my final semester of university.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Will look for that.

Comment: This answer is quite a fascinating topic, but it's still short of the answer the question's author was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might enjoy this [RasterTest](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/raster).
[image]